# Cannot save Oauth Conset Screen for Apis and Service in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

In the Oauth Consent Screen for GCP APIs, when filling in the App Info, App Domain, and Developer contact info, I click save and continue and get an error message saying:

> An error saving your app has occurred.

Looking at the HTTP Response I see these details:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":3,
      "message":"The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid.",
      "details":[
         {
            "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
            "violations":[
               {
                  "type":"client_auth_config",
                  "subject":"?error_code=9&error_field_name=UpdateBrandWithMaskRequest.brand_id&error_field_value=0"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: From the error message, it seems to be an issue with the brand field. Do you already have an existing brand? If not, you will have to create one. I would recommend following the instructions in the attached article in regards to configuring the Oauth consent screens https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients#configuring_consent_screen

Comment: Running this command (gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands list) in the terminal gives this error (INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument). Any other way to determine if i have an existing brand?